# Unexpected token '>' Using Array.some() With Karma and PhantomJS

Tags: unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am getting the following error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'
   at myAngularControllerPath.js:9
```

Navigating to that file I find that I am using the Array.some() function like so:

```
return list.some(x => isListItemGood(x));
```

When I run Karma with Chrome specified in the karma.conf.js file I do not get this error.

According to http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/ , PhantomJS support all 10 new array features of ES5 and Array.some() was introduced in ES5 according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some. I installed PhantomJS using 'npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher' which has 2.1.7 listed as the PhantomJS version in its dependencies.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: I think the problem is the lambda expression. The => is probably not supported.

Comment: Hey Stefan, thanks for looking into this. At the bottom of the question I provided references that say all versions that I am using should support the lambda. Do you think those references are not accurate?

Comment: Maybe. It was my first guess when i read that it is working properly in chrome. Have you tried using a normal function instead? Is it working then?

Comment: Yes because that would remove the part it is confused on so naturally it wouldn't get caught. This question is specifically geared towards why is it throwing the error when it should not (per references) rather than work arounds. I use quite a bit of ES5+ in this code base so one work around can quickly turn into 100s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

["Arrow functions" are not supported by PhantomJS 2.x](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#phantom)

PhantomJS only supports a small subset of ES6.

Comment: Hi Artjom, you linked to an ES6 compatibility table, I provided reference showing .some() was introduced in ES5. Just to clarify are you saying arrow functions(lambdas) were introduced in ES6? I think thay may be the case as I see it here being introduced in 6 as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. The issue is not at all about `Array.prototype.some`, because if it were, this would have been a TypeError and not a SyntaxError.

Comment: To add up to this question. Maybe you can achieve the results you want, using the arrow functions, by using a js transpiler like [babelJS](https://babeljs.io)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder Stefan, I have been meaning to look into it for a while now and this might be the straw that broke the camels back so to speak.